# Merge 'tileset images' into a single background using Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rmagick

I have a table that is 26 squares by 26 squares. Each square is going to be 30px * 30px.

Given the tiles

- upper_left.png
- upper_right.png
- upper_wall.png

and:

- left_wall.png
- right_wall.png

and:

- bottom_left.png
- bottom_wall.png
- bottom_right.png

I aim to comprise a background that is 780px*780px.
For the sake of speed and to prevent possible rendering errors, I want these tilesets to be composited into one big background. Making 8 tiles was easy, but I'm not a designer...
I believe I need to use an image library like RMagick to put them together, but I have no idea where to begin.

Ideally I'd like to just iterate over the image as though it were a multidimensional array of 26 rows and columns. That way I could just load up each spot with the image I need, and write it out to a file.

Can anybody point me in the right direction as to how I can manipulate images using a program?

The eventual goal is to just upload a tile_set.zip with the 8 images to the server, and have it do this on its own.

But for now, just a simple Ruby shell script would suffice.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I won't write the script for you, but ImageMagick's [+append and -append](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/layers/#append) are the tools that will solve this. The corresponding RMagick documentation is [here](http://www.imagemagick.org/RMagick/doc/ilist.html#append).

Comment: It worked perfectly, although for some odd reason, doing it entirely in memory doesn't work.

I have to save rows made with append(false) to disk, and then do append(true) on those.

I can only assume it's a bug; but it happens on a local Windows machine and my shared server, both with Ruby 1.8.6.

Comment: Cool. RMagick can be a memory hog, at least in my experience. 780x780 final size certainly isn't enormous or anything though. I wonder what's up with it.

Comment: @x1a4 I think it has something to do with appending an image [in memory] to itself. I haven't tried to set up a debugger or anything but I think it's entering an infinite loop.

http://pastie.org/960707

If I get rid of the second << row1, the code works just fine.

Comment: I do see that `row2` isn't being appended to `final`

Do you want to append row1 multiple times to the final image? What if you use `final << row1.dup` instead?

Comment: That's not my production code, I actually have 3 rows in the production and it goes
final << row1
24.times do
final << row2
end
final << row3

That was just the simplest example of the 'bug'

I'll try the .dup though

Comment: Awesome, I just put row2.dup into the loop and it works:
i.e: http://pastie.org/960774

It still seems odd that an image object in memory doesn't behave the same as an image from the disk.